# Views mapping error in spring boot application

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I'm trying to integrate spring boot plugin in my spring mvc application, but I'm always getting this mapping error:

```
Error resolving template "test", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers
```

project looks like this:
[image: project]

In application.properties:

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix: views/
spring.mvc.view.suffix: .jsp
```

in controller

```
@Controller
public class MainController {
...
  @RequestMapping("/test")
    public String test(RedirectAttributes attributes) {
        return "test";
    }
...
```

I've tried to use InternalResourceViewResolver

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class MvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{
   @Bean
    public ViewResolver getViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("views/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return resolver;
    } 
   @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(
            DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    } }
```

But always getting the same error

I've tried to change prefix like this

```
resolver.setPrefix("/views/");
```

or

```
 resolver.setPrefix("resources/views/");
```

or

```
resolver.setPrefix("classpath:/views/");
```

But if I replace InternalResourceViewResolver for TemplateResolver

```
  @Bean
    public TemplateResolver templateResolver() {
    TemplateResolver templateResolver = new ClassLoaderTemplateResolver();
    templateResolver.setPrefix("views/");
    templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
    return templateResolver;
    }
```

And it works with html files.

pom.xml dependencies

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.9</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.4.Final</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javassist</groupId>
            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            <version>3.12.1.GA</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-sample-web-ui-archetype</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
            <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: What happens when you put this into `templates` ?

Comment: Result is the same. I've tried to put views in every folder, but always getting this error

Comment: Is it possible that the problem is in using JSP? See also: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html#boot-features-jsp-limitations

Comment: Remove the `spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf` dependency in `pom.xml` and test!

Comment: after removing this dependency I got this error javax.el.ExpressionFactory.newInstance()Ljavax/el/ExpressionFactory;

Comment: OK. You should put all the `jsp` pages in the `WEB-INF` directory. For example, In eclipse your `test.jsp` should be in `src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\views\test.jsp` . Change your property `spring.mvc.view.prefix= /WEB-INF/views/`.  This should work! Let me know